# How to use the conditional operator to assign an ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, conditional-operator

I have four forms on a single page and I want to assign a single password validation function for all of them. I want to get the ID of the current password field and do further validation.

I get my ID of the current input password field like this:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

Now I want use ternary `if` to check for the ID and assign value to a variable. For example:

```
var a
if id==1
  a= "a";
else if id==2
  a= "b";
else if id==3
  a = "c"
else if id==4
  a = "d"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So, have you tried using a conditional operator? Please show us your attempt.

Comment: `var a = "abcd"[id-1]`

Comment: Why not just use an object? `const obj = {1: "a", 2: "b", 3: "c", 4: "d"}; var a = obj[id];`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By ternary operator you are referring to this one:

```
var value = (condition) 
    ? 'result if condition is true' 
    : 'result if condition is false';
```

I think using an object or a `switch` should be more clear.

For example:

```
var values = {
    1: 'a',
    2: 'b',
    3: 'c',
    4: 'd',
}

var id = $(this).attr('id');
var result = values[ id ] ? values[ id ] : 'default';

// Alternative syntax using the || operator
var result = values[ id ] || 'default';
```

Using a `switch` statment.

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var result = getValue( id );

function getValue( id ) {
    switch( id ) {
        case 1: return 'a';
        case 2: return 'b';
        default: return 'default value';
    }
}
```

Comment: Object is more efficient (about `O(1)` access), the bindings can be modified at run-time, and it produces cleaner code. So go with objects.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone:) Helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use the ternary operator:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var a = (id==1) ? "a" : (id==2) ? "b" : (id==3) ? "c" : (id==4) ? "d" : undefined;
```

Although if you need to do several such comparisons of the same variable using a `switch` would be a better choice:

```
var a;
switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
  case 1:
    a = "a";
    break;
  case 2:
    a = "b";
    break;
  case 3:
    a = "c";
    break;
  case 4:
    a = "d";
    break;
}
```

And if values of id are really consecutive numbers you may even use an array instead:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var a = [, "a", "b", "c", "d"][+id];
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var something = ["a", "b", "c", "ddddd"];

$("form").on("submit", function(evt) {

  evt.preventDefault();
  
  var $password = $(this).find("[name='password']");
  var bla = something[ +$password[0].id - 1 ]; // -1 since it's index (0) based
  
  console.log(bla)
  

});
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="1" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<form>
  <input id="3" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```